# Not able to connect with slack_rtm

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, slack-api

I'm trying to build a slack bot with this [turorial](https://hackernoon.com/a-guide-to-building-a-multi-featured-slackbot-with-python-73ea5394acc) i managed with all the modules except the slack

when I am trying to connect the slack_rtm having error like this. I'm using python 3.7.5, slackclient==1.3.1 and also using proper app token. Im stuck here for long time please help!

```
    Failed RTM connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Geeksters-Slack-Chatbot-master\venv\lib\site-packages\slackclient\client.py", line 140, in rtm_connect
    self.server.rtm_connect(use_rtm_start=with_team_state, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Geeksters-Slack-Chatbot-master\venv\lib\site-packages\slackclient\server.py", line 163, in rtm_connect
    raise SlackLoginError(reply=reply)
slackclient.server.SlackLoginError
Connection Failed
```

check my code

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
SLACK_API_TOKEN = "Unsing_proper_token_here"

client = SlackClient(SLACK_API_TOKEN)

def say_hello(data):
    if 'Hello' in data['text']:
        channel_id = data['channel']
        thread_ts = data['ts']
        user = data['user']

        client.api_call('chat.postMessage',
            channel=channel_id,
            text="Hi <@{}>!".format(user),
            thread_ts=thread_ts
        )

if client.rtm_connect():
    while client.server.connected is True:
        for data in client.rtm_read():
            if "type" in data and data["type"] == "message":
                say_hello(data)
else:
    print("Connection Failed")
```

Comment: Are you using the bot or user OAUTH token

Comment: BOT OAUTH TOKEN

Comment: Try using the user oauth token

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with RTM when using the OAUTH tokens with the version of slackclient you are using. I suggest trying to revert back to the legacy token that can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/legacy/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens). For more on this issue i suggest you look at the github [issue](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/326)

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the Slack App. RTM isn't supported for the new Slack App granular scopes (see [python client issue #584](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/584) and [node client issue #921](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/921)). If you want to use RTM, you can create a [classic slack app](https://api.slack.com/apps?new_classic_app=1) with the OAuth Scope `bot`. Note that [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955434/failed-rtm-connect-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-slack-with-rtm-api) has been asked before.